# Windows 8.1 fail upgrade, rebooting

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-8.1-upgrade

I own a Asus vivobook, which has a Windows 8 pro installed and has a secondary SSD for faster boot up only, not storage.

When I try to upgrade to 8.1, I hit a fail upgrade 0x80004003.

Now every time I login, the 8.1 installer will run at the background, this causes my PC to crash.

How can I upgrade it, or maybe disabled the upgrade?

Comment: Sounds like a driver conflict

Answer (score 0):

I just went through an entire day and night of pain.  I had 8.1 installed and stable for a few months but yesterday went to a vicious cycle of crash loops.

Finally got fed up and went back and did a fresh install of Windows 8.

Here are some methods from Microsoft support on addressing this particular error code:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-windows_install/error-on-installing-windows-81-0x80004003/39b9554a-59d7-4f79-96f9-e346ae07c9a8

Let me know if these help.

The other thing you need to check is if you have encryption on any of your drives. Disable that and see if that solves the problem.  You will probably need to boot into safe mode to disable the decryption, but I don't know for sure.